# Perguntas específicas sobre sistemas

Tags: suporte

Acredito que vários usuários aqui possivelmente trabalham com sistemas de terceiros, estes também, provavelmente privados.

Gostaria de saber, se posso por exemplo, criar uma tag para o sistema específico, mas claro, sem que a pergunta fuja do contexto "programação".

Comment: Já acontece com alguns softwares (nao vou colocar aqui no post quais pra nao divulgar). Só são fechadas quando não correspondem ao escopo e às regras usuais. Só que quando a tag não interfere na pergunta, não deve ser posta. Inclusive, links para sites e produtos de terceiros se não tiverem relação com a dúvida podem ser considerados spam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estritamente podemos dizer que pode, se realmente for programação. É claro que pode ser que aconteça de ninguém mais poder responder e classificar o conteúdo. E isso não seria bom para o site, afinal nosso objetivo não é só prover informação, é prover algo de qualidade, que tenha possibilidade de contestação.

Não posso falar por todos, mas é aceitável pelas regras, mas arriscado pelo objetivo do site.